# Getting video Ids from youtube playlist & downloading them

Tags: android, listview, video, youtube, youtube-api

so I'm currently working on a project... I want to create an Array containing the Ids of videos from a youtube playlist.. Also i wanna download a specific video when user click on download button, how can i do that?
Also, another question:
I have created a ListView, and set when the user click on one of the rows, `String clicked = videoIds.get(position);`.  But i want to get the clicked string to use in another methods, like when he clicks the download button, how can i do that too?
Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/t/terms

> You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content.

Comment: Like, okay but i wanna use it for personal usage, i want to show some playlists on my device and pick a video from it and just click download and watch it later... I won't make this app public lol. P.S.: like how tubemate download any video from any website, how can i do that?